# formBuilder - How to add an entity?

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

I have two classes : Class and Students. Each class contain one or many student.

In my form (create student), I want a scroll selector with all the available class to put my student in a class.

I have do that :

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('classe', 'entity', array(
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'MyCoolBundle:Classe',
            'query_builder' => function(ClasseRepository $cr) {
                return $cr->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
            }))
    ;
}
```

But the result is :

```
Could not load type "entity"
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

Comment: Have you find your answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the doc you've to rewrite the field type:

**[Extract from doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)**

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
// ...

$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
    'choice_label' => 'username',
));
```

So I think you should try something like :

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
...
...

$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('classe', EntityType::class, array(
        'required' => true,
        'class' => 'MyCoolBundle:Classe',
        'query_builder' => function(ClasseRepository $cr) {
            return $cr->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
        }))
;
```

Comment: I don't have any Type for my Classe Entity